# Signal Conditioning of the conductive Polymer?

Tags: sensor, signal, signal-theory

I have a conductive piezoresistive polymer which gives the resistance changes according to the applied force and strain. What could the first step to start the signal conditioning. The goal of the Signal conditioning is to have the signal output is between 0-5 volts for the input force.

Comment: First, conductive polymer is not a piezo.  Second, we can't say how to condition the signal since you haven't specified what the input signal looks like, and what about that signal you want to "condition" in what way.  This second point really should have been obvious.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: He said [piezoresistive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoresistive_effect), not piezoelectric. "piezo" is a root that means "pressure", nothing else.

Comment: The conductive polymer responds to force and strain. and gives the Resistance change as a output signal. in every case the resistance is approximately same but some creep behavior is there. So i am really confused regarding how to start designing signal conditioning circuits, the basic ideas i have that we first need the voltage divider circuit and then need the amplifier to amplify the output of voltage divider circuit output. It will be grateful if you give me some informative website or forum where i can get the more info.  Thanks guys. anyway, i know my questions sounds very crazy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to determine what the magnitude of the resistance change is going to be in your application. You'll want to check whether that change is linear or highly nonlinear over the range of operation, and determine how much accuracy and resolution you're going to need. You'll also need to determine any additional constraints, such as how much voltage and/or current you can apply to the material.

Once you have that kind of information, you can start to think about how to convert the resistance change into a voltage signal you can measure.